# Xamarin Bluetooth Sending Data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android

**Now, before we start, can I just say that I have read the other questions similar to this, and none of them help.**

I am trying to send a string to a raspberry pi with an Xamarin app, anyway, here is my code:

```
private async void Send(string stuff)
{
    try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stuff);
            await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
}
```

but I get this error:

***Exception of type: 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.***

I have checked if all of the variables that I insert into the function are not null, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the full exception/stacktrace?

Comment: @SushiHangover nothing, that is all I got feelsbadman

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"? There will be some type of stacktrace available since it is a *managed* exception.